# Limit of this matrix equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Suppose we have a matrix $A$
$$ A=
\begin{bmatrix}
    0    & 1   & 0 \\
    0    & 0   & 1 \\
    0    & 0   & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$
its transposed matrix $A^T$, and $Z_0=I$. And we have updating equation  $$Z_{k+1}=\frac{AZ_kA^T+A^TZ_kA}{\|AZ_kA^T+A^TZ_kA\|_F}, k=0, 1,\dots $$

the matrix norm $\|\cdot\|_F$ i use here is Frobenius norm. Then, I want to solve $$\lim_{k\rightarrow+\infty}Z_{2k}$$

I calculated for $k=1,2$
$$ Z_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}
\begin{bmatrix}
    1    & 0   & 0 \\
    0    & 2   & 0 \\
    0    & 0   & 1 
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
Z_2=
2
\begin{bmatrix}
    \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}   &  0  & 0 \\
    0    & \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}   & 0 \\
    0    & 0   & \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} 
\end{bmatrix}, $$
but I don't know what to do from here. Can someone tell me what should be the next step?

I know the answer and it will be $$\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
    0.5774    & 0   & 0 \\
    0    & 0.5774   & 0 \\
    0    & 0   & 0.5774 \\
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}
$$ but I have no idea what should be the intermediate steps.

Comment: What norm are you using?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt frobenius norm. I edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sequence is a [power iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) corresponding to the linear map $\Phi: \Bbb R^{3 \times 3} \to \Bbb R^{3 \times 3}$ defined by
$$
\Phi(X) = AXA^T + A^TXA.
$$
With that said, we will be able to deduce the behavior of this sequence if we find the largest (in magnitude) eigenvalues of $\Phi$. One approach to this problem is to compute the matrix of this map, then compute the eigenvalues of the resulting matrix. Using the properties of [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), we find that the matrix of this map is
$$
[\Phi] = A \otimes A + A^T \otimes A^T = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|ccc|ccc}  
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right).
$$
Applying a permutation similarity associated with the permutation $[1\ 5\ 9\mid4\ 8\mid 2\ 6\mid 3\mid 7]$ yields
$$
M = \left(\begin{array}{ccc|cc|cc|c|c} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{array}\right).
$$
In fact, the invariant subspaces corresponding to the block-structure above correspond to the diagonals of $X$.

We see that the largest eigenvalues of $\Phi$ correspond to the upper-left block. These are $\pm \sqrt{2}$,  with associated eigenvectors $(1,\pm \sqrt{2}, 1)$. These two eigenvectors span an eigenspace of $M$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $2$ of $\Phi^2$. As it turns out, the matrix subspace corresponding to this eigenspace is
$$
\left\{\pmatrix{a & 0 & 0\\ 0 & b & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a} : a,b \in \Bbb R\right\}.
$$
Because $Z_0 = I$ is an element of this subspace, it follows that $\Phi^2(Z_0) = 2Z_0$, so that $Z_{2} = 2Z_0/\|2 Z_0\| = 2I/(2I) = I/\sqrt{3}$, and correspondingly $Z_{2k} = I/\sqrt{3}$ for all $k$.

---

Attempt at a cleaner approach: we note that $\Phi$ is given by
$$
\Phi \pmatrix{x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13}\\x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23}\\ x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33}} = 
\pmatrix{x_{22} & x_{23} & 0\\x_{32} & x_{33} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0} + \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&x_{11} & x_{12}\\0 & x_{21} & x_{22}}.
$$
We can see that if $\Phi(X) = \lambda X$ with $\lambda \neq 0$, we must have $x_{31} = x_{13} = 0$. That simplifies the equation to
$$
\pmatrix{x_{22} & x_{23} & 0\\x_{32} & x_{33} & 0\\0 & 0 & 0} + 
\pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&x_{11} & x_{12}\\0 & x_{21} & x_{22}} = 
\lambda\pmatrix{x_{11} & x_{12} & 0\\x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23}\\ 0 & x_{32} & x_{33}}.
$$

Comment: sorry but I'm not familiar with "permutation similarity" method, how did you get $M$? I still don't understand there.

Comment: @J.Maisel No problem. $M$ is the matrix $P^{-1}[\Phi]P = P^T[\Phi]P$, where $P$ is the [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix) whose first column is column $1$ of the identity matrix, second column is column $5$ of the identity matrix, third column is column $9$ of the identity matrix, and so forth.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Show by induction that $Z_k$ is of the form

$$Z_k=\begin{bmatrix}a_k&0&0\\0&b_k&0\\0&0&a_k\end{bmatrix}$$

and that $Z_{2k}$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix. Since $\|Z_k\|_F=1$, it follows that $Z_{2k}=I/\|I\|_F$.